# Is there any way to include platform specific files for a Meteor Mobile package?

Tags: meteor

I'd like to be able to include files based off of which platform the package is being run/built for.

For example, inside my package.js file it would be nice to have something like this:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    if (Meteor.cordova.isiOS || mobileSettings.isiOS)
        api.addFiles('lib/ios.css')
    else if (Meteor.cordova.isAndroid || mobileSettings.isAndroid)
        api.addFiles('lib/android.css')
    else
        api.addFiles('lib/default.css')
})
```

Ideally, it would nice if there was a way for the application developer to specify these settings for the package directly from within the [mobile-config.js](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs) file. There appears to be a way to do this for Cordova plugins, but not for meteor packages.

Is there any way to accomplish anything similar to this?

Comment: have you found a way? I am looking for a helper that I can use in my javascript code that uses one function is iOS and another is Android.